# BoxLayout refuses to honor preferred size of JButton

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, layout-manager

I have been working on a small project that is supposed to simulate a gambling game. Unfortunately, I ran into some odd issues while working with `BoxLayout`. To the best of my knowledge, `LayoutManager`s usually honor any component's preferred size. However, in the below code, `BoxLayout` does not.

Here is my code thus far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;



public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Suit-Up");
      frame.setContentPane(makeGUI());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setSize(900,450);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static JPanel makeGUI()
    {
      JPanel main = new JPanel();
      main.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(900,450));
      main.setBackground(Color.red);

      JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel();
      infoPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(infoPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
      infoPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900,60));
      infoPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
      main.add(infoPanel);

      JPanel infoText = new JPanel();
      infoText.setLayout(new BoxLayout(infoText, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      infoPanel.add(infoText);

      JPanel moneyText = new JPanel();
      moneyText.setLayout(new BoxLayout(moneyText, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
      infoText.add(moneyText);

      JPanel lastGameText = new JPanel();
      lastGameText.setLayout(new BoxLayout(lastGameText, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
      infoText.add(lastGameText);

      JButton playAgain = new JButton("Play Again ($20)");
      playAgain.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,60));
      infoPanel.add(playAgain);

      JButton finish = new JButton("End Session");
      finish.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,60));
      infoPanel.add(finish);

      JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel();
      cardPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cardPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
      main.add(cardPanel);

      return main;
    }
}
```

Despite specifying preferred sizes for both `JButton`s, they do not change their sizes. I have tried `setMaximumSize()` and `setMinimumSize()` as well, but neither had any effect.

Am I overlooking something obvious, or is this a limitation of `BoxLayout`?

Comment: you can always use `BoxLayout`, but nest the components...

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean by nesting. I'm relatively new to layout managers.

Comment: if you place the button on a panel and add the panel directly to the container instead of the button, the panel will be resized instead of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"To the best of my knowledge, LayoutManagers usually honor any component's preferred size"* - That's actually not true.  preferred/min/max size are just "hints" that layout managers MAY use to determine how best to layout there contents.  Layout managers are allowed to simply ignore them if they want to.

From the JavaDocs

> BoxLayout **attempts** to arrange components at their preferred widths
>   (for horizontal layout) or heights (for vertical layout). For a
>   horizontal layout, if not all the components are the same height,
>   BoxLayout attempts to make all the components as high as the highest
>   component. If that's not possible for a particular component, then
>   BoxLayout aligns that component vertically, according to the
>   component's Y alignment. By default, a component has a Y alignment of
>   0.5, which means that the vertical center of the component should have the same Y coordinate as the vertical centers of other components with
>   0.5 Y alignment.
>
> Similarly, for a vertical layout, BoxLayout attempts to make all
>   components in the column as wide as the widest component. If that
>   fails, it aligns them horizontally according to their X alignments.
>   For PAGE_AXIS layout, horizontal alignment is done based on the
>   leading edge of the component. In other words, an X alignment value of
>   0.0 means the left edge of a component if the container's ComponentOrientation is left to right and it means the right edge of
>   the component otherwise.

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue with the preferred sizes I used, though. Theres plenty of room to fit the `JButton`s in the `JPanel`, they just refuse have their size modified by anything but adding more text to their labels. I have read the documentation but I haven't seen anything that explains what I am running into right now.

Comment: @Thrfoot I ran you test code and `BoxLayout` simply refuses to use the `preferredSize` of the `JButton` regardless of what I tried.  It's generally inadvisable to manipulate the preferred size of components in this way, normally we are encouraged to use either layout managers or override the `getPreferredSize` method directly.  Oddly, `FlowLayout` worked just fine...

Comment: Thats strange... Well, I guess I won't be able to get it to work with `BoxLayout` then. Would you recommend any other layout managers that I can get a more or less similar effect with?

Comment: @Thrfoot Seen as you're setting the width and height to be equal, try using a `FlowLayout` aligned to the left...

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I guess sometimes things just don't work.

Comment: The answer is to invoke boxLayout.invalidateLayout(container);  This will flush the previous preferred sizes it has cached, request new ones from the components, and adjust accordingly.