# How to give a preffered size to the JButton?

Tags: java, swing

```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.*;
   class MainGui{
         JFrame frame = new JFrame();
         JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
         JButton newBut = new JButton("New Game");
         JButton continueBut = new JButton("Continue");
         JButton exitBut = new JButton("Exit");
         JLabel backImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\BSK\\Desktop\\game5.jpg"));
         public MainGui(){
             frame.setSize(600,800);
             frame.setVisible(true);
             frame.setResizable(false);
             setButtonSize();
             frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
             frame.setContentPane(backImage);
             frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
             insertBlankArea(frame);
             frame.getContentPane().add(newBut);
             insertBlankArea(frame);
             frame.getContentPane().add(continueBut);
             insertBlankArea(frame);
             frame.getContentPane().add(exitBut);
             frame.setSize(799,800);

      }
      public void insertBlankArea(JFrame frame){
            frame.getContentPane().add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(280,155)));
      }
      public void setButtonSize(){
            Dimension dim = new Dimension(100,100);//here is the problem,i am not getting the desired dimension and the size of buttons remains the default.
            newBut.setPreferredSize(dim);
            continueBut.setPreferredSize(dim);
            exitBut.setPreferredSize(dim);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
            MainGui mainGui = new MainGui();
      }
  }
```

So iam not getting the defined size for the buttons but when i set  `frame.setResizable(false);` then when i stretch the screen the button's height increases but its width still remains the same.
So please tell me what is going wrong?  [image: this is the output]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226622/boxlayout-refuses-to-honor-preferred-size-of-jbutton

Comment: Not related, Hard coding a system path, might will give trouble at the time of deployment of the application, consider how to [add images to Java Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), for a way to organize the project structure. Moreover, try to write `frame.setVisible(true)` as the last line, preceeded by `frame.pack()` once you have added all components to the `JFrame`. Do not call it before that, not a good practice, and a reason why you have to set size again, instead call `frame.pack()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reading your short descrption, I have no idea what your problem is. But based solely on the question title

> "How to give a preffered size to the JButton?"

Don't. Let the the layout manager handle this for you. If you want a bigger button, you can use `JButton.setMargins(Insets)` and/or `JButton.setFont(Font)` where you specify a bigger font.

If you want you button stretched or *not* to stretch, You need to select an appropriate layout manager, that will or won't respect the buttons preferred size. For instance, BorderLayout and GridLayout *won't* respect preferred sizes and will stretch the button the fit, and FlowLayout, BoxLayout, and GridBagLayout *will* respect the preferred size. As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376596/2587435)

[image]

---

See example with GridBagLayout

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class MainGui {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton newBut = new JButton("New Game");
    JButton continueBut = new JButton("Continue");
    JButton exitBut = new JButton("Exit");
    JLabel backImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
            getClass().getResource("images.jpg")));

    public MainGui() {
        backImage.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setContentPane(backImage);
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        mainPanel.setOpaque(false);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        mainPanel.add(newBut, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 1;
        mainPanel.add(continueBut, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 2;
        mainPanel.add(exitBut, gbc);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(250, 275);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                MainGui mainGui = new MainGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here's with nesting panels which will give the same result

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class MainGui {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton newBut = new JButton("New Game");
    JButton continueBut = new JButton("Continue");
    JButton exitBut = new JButton("Exit");
    JLabel backImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
            getClass().getResource("images.jpg")));

    public MainGui() {
        backImage.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        frame.setContentPane(backImage);
        JPanel p1= new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        p1.setOpaque(false);
        p1.add(newBut);
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        p2.setOpaque(false);
        p2.add(continueBut);
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        p3.setOpaque(false);
        p3.add(exitBut);

        frame.add(p1);
        frame.add(p2);
        frame.add(p3);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(250, 275);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                MainGui mainGui = new MainGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please tell me one more thing,in your first case why we need `backImage.setLayout(new BorderLayout());`.I have noticed that without it image is displaying but not buttons on it,what is the reason for this,please reply.Thanx.

Comment: Because JLabel has default null layout. In order to add to a null layout, you need to specify the bounds for the components you add to it. Like `panel.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 300); label.add(panel);`. With a layout manager, setting the bounds is unnecessary as the layout manager takes care of sizing and positioning for you

Comment: it means without setting bounds you cannot add components to a null layout container

Comment: Yes that's correct. Test it out. You should always use a layout manager though. The to main containers come already with default layout manager. JFrame=BorderLayout, JPanel=FlowLayout

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and choose the most appropriate one for your situation. You should also avoid explicitly setting sizes (ie: `setSize`, `setMinimumSize`, `setMaximumSize`, and `setPreferredSize`) because those methods are the responsibility of the layout manager. You may also be interested in reading [this question on whether or not the use of the different set size methods should be avoided or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi).

Finally, you should not be calling your `MainGUI` class outside of the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Most Swing GUI-related methods are not thread safe and therefore require being executed in the EDT. Below is a corrected version of your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainGui mainGui = new MainGui();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: oh! i am new to java so i dont know much about it.